# Get single value from array - Array fetch from URL

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, multidimensional-array

Hi i am trying to fetch single value from below Array example -

i want to fetch **order_id** and **name** -

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://example.com/index.php?route=feed/rest_api/orders&key=test219';

        $json = file_get_contents($url);

    echo '<pre>'; echo $json; echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Array showing

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 6
            [name] => zoraya panansar
            [status] => Complete
            [date_added] => 2014-01-24 23:06:09
            [products] => 4
            [total] => 14.8000
            [address_1] => 345 goldhawk road
            [address_2] => hammersmith
            [city] => london
            [Postcode] => w6 0wz
            [Country] => United Kingdom
            [Email] => zpanansar@yahoo.com
            [Tele.] => 0786870150
        )
```

I already tried

```
echo $json->order_id;
```

and

```
echo $json[0]['order_id'];
```

but its not working... Please help

Comment: have you tried echo $json['order_id']

Comment: I can't see you actually **decoding** that JSON anywhere... did you forget to post it or did you forget to add `json_decode($json)` ?

Comment: it looks like the output from this url is a string representation of an array in php. so basically you're getting the string when running `file_get_contents`. so you cannot access `order_id` from `$json`

Comment: yes i have tried with json_decode($json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the data that the server is returning. Instead of returning you a json object, the server is returning you the `print_r()` output over an array.

If its your server, then stop the print, and use `json_encode()` over the array before printing.

If it's not your server, then you have to parse the values from the text. You can use `preg_match_all()` for this.

```
preg_match_all("/\[order_id\] => ([^\n\r]+)/", $json, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

There may be built-in php function that can take such `print_r()` output and revert back into a php array, but I don't know about it!

Comment: yes but it showing in array - result - Array ( [0] => zoraya panansar [1] => ciria ann nuqui )

Comment: I want to show with array like - zoraya panansar <br> ciria ann nuqui

Comment: try using `implode('<br>', $m[1]);` or `join('<br>', $m[1]);`

Comment: Sorry my mistake ... Working now

Comment: can i get multiple value in same implode?

Answer (score 1):

index.php is returning wrong data, if you look closer then you will see it is trying to send success = false result as json data but probably for testing purposes, it is also returning array content directly before the json data.

Besides, if this is supposed to be a json result then you need to use json_decode before using  the returned json object as a class object like $json->order_id.

This is what I get when I try your current URL With the parameters you provided: Look at the last line:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 6
            [name] => zoraya panansar
            [status] => Complete
            [date_added] => 2014-01-24 23:06:09
            [products] => 4
            [total] => 14.8000
            [address_1] => 345 goldhawk road
            [address_2] => hammersmith
            [city] => london
            [Postcode] => w6 0wz
            [Country] => United Kingdom
            [Email] => zpanansar@yahoo.com
            [Tele.] => 0786870150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 5
            [name] => ciria ann nuqui
            [status] => Complete
            [date_added] => 2014-01-24 17:58:36
            [products] => 7
            [total] => 36.4000
            [address_1] => 345 goldhawk road 
            [address_2] => hammersmith
            [city] => london
            [Postcode] => w6 0wz
            [Country] => United Kingdom
            [Email] => joycernuqui@yahoo.com
            [Tele.] => 07515732291
        )
)
{"success":false}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is different query.

Comment: @user1250920, You need to check index.php no matter what the query is, it is not returning "only" json data. After fixing it then you need to use json_decode(file_get_contents($url)) to decode the text to use as json object.

Comment: @user1250920 - Because index.php in the URL doesn't return correct data - as I explained. It needs to be checked first. json_decode is the next part after fixing the problem in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Change the response from the url to json (Use json_encode function)
The last Row in url script should be

```
    echo json_encode($some_array);
```

And than if you want the content:

```
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),TRUE);
    if(!is_array($array)){
      echo 'bad response';
      exit();
     }
     var_dump($array);
     echo $array[0]['order_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, got the - bad response